# Install fails - 'unable to install GRUB in /dev/sda' problem

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, system-installation

I have a Lenovo S series running Windows 8.1 (pre-installed). I downloaded Ubuntu 15.04 onto a USB stick and followed the instructions as outlined in the [Quick Install From USB](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStickQuick) docs.

Secure Boot is disabled.

I can successfully boot into Ubuntu and begin the installation process. Around 80% of the way through I get the fatal error:

`unable to install GRUB in /dev/sda`

I've been through many of the other posts here on this issue, but cannot find a solution that seems to work in my situation. I have tried the *'Try without installing'* option, and attempting to install after booting to desktop, but I get the same problem.

As far as I can tell, the issue is with the partition that is being attempted to install to.

**Update:** Boot Info here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/12447125/

Is anyone able to offer any advice on what might be causing this, or how I should choose/prepare a partition in order to install successfully?

Thanks

Comment: Are you installing in BIOS mode on gpt partitioned drive. Better to install in UEFI mode. Then it will use existing ESP - efi system partition. Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Comment: Try running Boot-Repairs fixes. You show signed kernels installed which should work with either Secure boot on or off. There used to be some systems with "locked" ESP - efi system partition. Some repaired with chkdsk from Windows or dosfsck `sudo dosfsck -t -a -w /dev/sda2` from Linux. Others had to totally back up ESP, erase it, then recreate with gparted as FAT32 with boot flag or using gdisk code ef00 so it is the new ESP and restore files.

Comment: Thanks, I'm slightly out of my depth here - boot-repair fixes seem to suggest: "reinstall grub-efi-amd64-signed of sda7 with sda2/boot/efi option". How would I go about doing this?

Comment: I ran `dosdsck` which found 1 dirty bit. I ran `apt-get install grub-efi-amd64-signed` and then tried the install again (complete wipe and install), which failed with the same problem. I'm assuming perhaps I need to 'reinstall ubuntu' without wiping, after having run the install grub command?

Comment: You should not have to reinstall Ubuntu. Did you get error message on the install of grub? Only use Something Else on reinstall if you do that. It may say overwriting Ubuntu, but erase entire drive. Supposedly that was fixed, but depends on version you are using.

Comment: Ok, I'm confused now. The only way I can even boot into Ubuntu is via the live USB - because Ubuntu hasn't installed properly. So to even have the option of re/installing grub, I have to boot from the live USB - which means I *must* re/install Ubuntu, otherwise it doesn't exist as a bootable option on my hard drive?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29295/discussion-between-duncanhall-and-oldfred).

Comment: I am not available currently for chat. But you show Ubuntu installed in your Summary report, but grub is not installed. So you should not need a full reinstall of Ubuntu, but only of grub. Let the auto fix in Boot-Repair run and see if it also gives errors or does actually install grub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution in my case was to enable the 'Both' option for UEFI/Legacy BIOS boot support, as well as setting the Secure Chip to 'Inactive'. After all previous failed attempts, I made the changes to both these settings at the same time, so it's possible only one of them was required to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

First, [disable Fast Startup](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/6320-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-8-a.html) in Windows. This feature is a good way to cause filesystem corruption (my nickname for it is "Fast Filesystem Corruption"), which in turn can cause any number of problems, including an inability to install GRUB -- precisely the symptom you're seeing.

After you've disabled Fast Startup, you can try running [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) or re-install Ubuntu. With any luck, disabling Fast Startup will enable either of these procedures to work, but I can't make any promises about that.

If you disable Fast Startup but can't seem to get GRUB installed, another option is to try my [rEFInd boot manager.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) You can try it risk-free by preparing a USB flash drive or CD-R with the appropriate version (see the [downloads page](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) for links). You should then be able to boot from the appropriate medium, which should let you boot either Windows or Ubuntu. If you can boot both OSes, you can install rEFInd via the PPA or Debian package to get it on your hard disk. One big caveat is that if there's filesystem damage that's preventing GRUB from installing, the same problem is likely to affect rEFInd. OTOH, it could be a bug in the GRUB installation script that's not shared by the rEFInd installation script, so rEFInd might work around such problems. If nothing else, using rEFInd on a USB drive or CD-R might be a useful temporary stopgap to get you into your regular Ubuntu installation. From there you'd need to do more detailed analysis to figure out what's causing the boot loader problems, but at least you'd have a way to boot.

Answer (score -1):

You are having problems with windows 8.1 secure boot. Try disabling UEFI following [this tutorial.](http://itsfoss.com/disable-uefi-secure-boot-in-windows-8/) And then install Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks, I should've mentioned that Secure Boot is already disabled.

Comment: Secure Boot problems normally manifest as an inability to boot into the installer at all. Secure Boot is designed to block pre-boot malware from booting at all. I've never heard of a Secure Boot problem enabling the installer to boot and run through to the point of installing the boot loader and *then* failing, and in fact the way it works, that symptom seems completely improbable. Also, "disabling UEFI" is entirely the ***WRONG*** thing to do in this situation, since Windows and Linux must boot in the same mode.